Cyrillic encoding has disappeared in ER-Assistant
I want to create an ER Diagram for a database, but besides Latin characters, other characters are not displayed correctly.
enter image description here
When I downloaded this program, at first everything was fine, but then the encoding somehow strangely disappeared
I tried to simply copy the Cyrillic text and paste it into ER-Assistant, but it didn’t work.
